# Spectral density of product

Tags: time-series

Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ stationary, zero mean, independent processes with $\phi_x(\lambda)$ and $\phi_y(\lambda)$ spectral densities.

How can I prove that the process $Z_t=X_tY_t$ has a spectral density:

$\phi_z(\lambda)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\phi_x(\lambda-\omega)\cdot\phi_y(\omega)d\omega$

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question needs some ideas from random processes and some from
Fourier theory.

The *autocorrelation function* of a (continuous-time finite-variance) stationary random process
$\{X_t\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$ is $R_X(t) = E[X_{\tau}X_{\tau+t}]$ and the
spectral density $S_X(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $R_x(t)$. For your
problem, the independence of the $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ processes gives that

$$R_Z(t) = E[Z_{\tau}Z_{\tau+t}] = E[X_{\tau}Y_{\tau}X_{\tau+t}Y_{\tau+t}]
= E[X_{\tau}X_{\tau+t}]E[Y_{\tau}Y_{\tau+t}]= R_X(t)R_Y(t).$$

So much so for random processes. From Fourier transform theory, we have
that the transform of a product of two functions is the convolution of their
Fourier transforms.  If you are not familiar with this, 
see, for example, the [last paragraph of Section 5.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Convolution_theorem) of the 
Wikipedia article on the Fourier transform.  Thus,
$$S_Z(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty S_X(\lambda)S_Y(\omega-\lambda)\,
\mathrm d\lambda.\tag{1}$$

For *your* particular application with a *discrete-time* random process
(a.k.a. time series), similar results apply but in $(1)$ the limits
work out to be $-\pi$ and $\pi$. (You will need to know about the discrete-time
Fourier transform to get to this). Note also
that you might be missing a $\frac{1}{2\pi}$
factor in the result you state as wanting to prove in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I don't need it in discrete time, I just didn't know what is the proper tag for this question.

Comment: Autocovariance function not autocorrelation, right?